# Check if postal code is in a range

Tags: ios, regex, postal-code

this might be a dumb question but I'm new to iOS programming and I just couldn't think of anything.
for my app I need to check if a certain postal code is in a range. It's easy to do for German or US codes which are plain numbers, but now I have to do it for canadian.

Example canadian postal code looks like this: A0A, J3X, R7N, V1M.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: do you want something like this: `^(A0A|J3X|R7N|V1M)$`  ?

Comment: @Fede oh god I feel really dumb now that I haven't though of this haha! Is there a similar thing for having ranges? For example V1M - V1Z?

Comment: I'll post an answer with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
^(A0A|J3X|R7N|V1M)$
```

If you want ranges you can do something like this:

```
^(A0A|J3X|R7N|V1[M-Z])$
                 ^--- Will match V1M until V1Z
```

Another example for range V1Z could be:

```
^(A0A|J3X|R7N|V[5-9][M-Z])$
                 ^--- Will match VxM until VxZ and V5x until V9x
```

If you just want a digit you can use `\d` (it's the shortcut for `[0-9]`). Same for `\w` that means `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

You can specify ranges using regex classes. Like:

```
[0-4]
[7-9]
[A-M]
[O-X]
```

---

[This answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19409948/703229) has a good description of how regular expression character class ranges work. ***To paraphrase:*** *you aren't just limited to letters and numbers (`[A-Z]` or `[0-9]`), but you should be careful attempting any more complicated ranges.*

A range will allow for any character between, [according to the list of ASCII characters](http://www.asciitable.com/), the start and end characters to match. This means any range is technically valid (you may just see odd results). For example, these two classes are the same:

```
[0-Z]
[0-9:;<=>?@A-Z]
```

Comment: Just be careful when you start to get fancy with character class ranges in regex. It literally goes from start to end through the [list of ASCII characters](http://www.asciitable.com/), so [`[0-Z]` would be the same as `[0-9:;<=>?@A-Z]`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19409948/703229).

Comment: @Sam yup, you are totally right. If you want I can update my answer with your comment